# Apache Doris: Tablet writer failed to write

Tags: database, open-source, data-warehouse, olap, data-ingestion

tablet_id=27306172, txn_id=28573520, err=-235

This error occurred when I was doing the data import and I believe there is something wrong with my version compaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the import speed is too fast and the compaction cannot keep up. The solution is as follows:

1. Reduce the import speed, such as increasing the checkpoint of flink.
2. Optimize compaction parameters, such as increase the parameter of be: max_tablet_version_num

If this doesn't solve your problem, welcome to the doris slack community, we will try to help you

Comment: Thank you, can you provide a link to Doris Slack community